# Fetch value at angular controller from ionic based radio button?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-controller

I am working on Ionic framework on frontend. Basically it is a Cordova app. I want to capture the radio button value in controller but as I'm new in it I don't know how exactly I'll get back my value and what I need to pass in NextQuestion() method in ionic. code is as below.

```
<div class="list list-inset padding">
        <ion-list radio-group>
            <ion-item class="item-remove-animate item-icon-right" ng-repeat="answer in CurrentQuestion.answersList" type="item-text-wrap">
                <ion-radio ng-value="'{{answer.AnswerID}}'">{{answer.Answer_en}}</ion-radio>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </div>
    <ion-buttons side="primary">
        <button class="button button-block button-calm" ng-click="NextQuestion()">
            Next
        </button>
    </ion-buttons>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `ng-model` for two-way binding, in your example, I will do this:

```
...
<ion-radio ng-model="userSelectedAnswer" ng-value="{{answer.AnswserID}}">
    {{answer.Answer_en}}
</ion-radio> 
...
```

Then you can use the selected value in your `NextQuestion` function like this:

```
console.log($scope.userSelectedAnswer);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ion-radio behavior like input radio of AngularJS.

Basically you need to do it like this (`$parent` is because of ng-repeat create a child scope for each item)

```
        <ion-list radio-group>
            <ion-item class="item-remove-animate item-icon-right" ng-repeat="answer in CurrentQuestion.answersList" type="item-text-wrap">
                <ion-radio ng-model="$parent.selectedAnswer" ng-value="'{{answer.AnswerID}}'">{{answer.Answer_en}}</ion-radio>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
```